# How do I change specific properties of an existing TextStyle?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a custom widget that basically adds a stroke to a text by taking a Text, wrapping it in a Stack with two texts, with one of them rendered with a stroke.

```
class BorderedText extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text displayText;
  final Color strokeColor;
  final double strokeWidth;

  BorderedText(this.displayText,
      {Key key, this.strokeColor = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 1.0})
      : assert(displayText != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            displayText.data,
            style: displayText.style
              ..foreground = Paint()
                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                ..color = strokeColor,
          ),
          displayText,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Intended way of usage:

```
BorderedText(
  Text(
    "Hello App",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 34.0,
      fontFamily: "LexendMega",
    ),
  ),
  strokeWidth: 6.0,
),
```

Sadly this code doesn't work because `foreground` is final. How can I address that?

- Can I make a complete copy of `displayText` parameter and be able to change its `foreground`?
- Can I make a copy of its `TextStyle`, only changing the foreground?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`TextStyle.copyWith`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/copyWith.html) for this. This will copy the parameters from your other text style and only changes the ones you supply. In your case it would looks like this:

```dart
Text(
  displayText.data,
  style: displayText.style.copyWith(
      foreground: Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        ..color = strokeColor
  ),
)
```

*By the way*: this method exists for many classes in the Flutter framework (where it makes sense) and it is very useful as you would need to manually type all the parameters otherwise.